# Display items custom options in magento onestepcheckout

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, custom-options, onestepcheckout

I have been struggling for almost 10 hours, how to achieve desired view of my onestepcheckout. I have downloaded Uni_Opcheckout extension and it is working ok, but in checkout review table is only product name in one line:

[image: now]

but I want my review table to look like:

[image]

Code that generates first view is located in opcheckout\onepage\review\info.phtml

```
 <tbody>
    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item):?>
    <tr>
        <td class="attributes-col"><?php echo $_item->getName() ?></td>
        <td class="a-center"><?php echo $_item->getQty() ?></td>
        <td class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

Can anyone help with this, please?

Regards

Comment: so you want custom options to be displayed along with your product name. Right?

Comment: Yes, i want my custom options right above product name.

Answer (score 2):

In every order item has attribute "product_options". You can fetch configurable attributes from this field.

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
<tr>
    <td class="attributes-col"><?php echo $_item->getName() ?>
        <?php
        $o = unserialize($_item->getData('product_options'));
        if (isset($o['attributes_info'])):
            $_options = $o['attributes_info'];
            foreach ($_options as $_option) {
                echo "<br/><b>" . $this->htmlEscape($_option['label']) . ":</b> " . $this->htmlEscape($_option['value']);
            } ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="a-center"><?php echo $_item->getQty() ?></td>
    <td class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()) ?></td>
</tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

Most right way is using magento functionality to retrieve options. See:

```
$helper   = Mage::helper('catalog/product_configuration');
foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item):
  $_options = $helper->getCustomOptions($_item);
  foreach ($_options as $_option) {
      $label = $this->htmlEscape($_option['label']);
      $value = $this->htmlEscape($_option['value']);
  } 
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But I can't get it work. Tried your first code snippet and it's not working for me. Seems like getData('product_options') doesn't pull out anything. I need to display my custom option (when you add item to basket you first need to entry which model in text box) for some items and attribute name with value for other products. Second code snippet generates error: Call to a member function getProduct() on a non-object in xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Configuration.php on line 47

Comment: Updated answer, see second snippet

Comment: Still can't get this work. I was close with this snippet:'<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
<?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item)?>
<?php endforeach ?>' but it generates thumbnail and remove icon, which I don't want. Then I did edit mytheme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml and get desired view to work, but with this you change not only chekcout/onepage but also checkout/cart view. How can I specify new default.phtml file ONLY for checkout/onepage? My opcheckout extension is located in /default/default/template/opcheckout/ folder...